# Podman only search in docker.io

Tags: registry, podman

I was configuring my podman to search in a many registries, but when I try to search only use docker.io, in the registries.conf specifies 4 registries to search (is V2):

```
# For more information on this configuration file, see containers-registries.conf(5).
#
# NOTE: RISK OF USING UNQUALIFIED IMAGE NAMES
# We recommend always using fully qualified image names including the registry
# server (full dns name), namespace, image name, and tag
# (e.g., registry.redhat.io/ubi8/ubi:latest). Pulling by digest (i.e.,
# quay.io/repository/name@digest) further eliminates the ambiguity of tags.
# When using short names, there is always an inherent risk that the image being
# pulled could be spoofed. For example, a user wants to pull an image named
# `foobar` from a registry and expects it to come from myregistry.com. If
# myregistry.com is not first in the search list, an attacker could place a
# different `foobar` image at a registry earlier in the search list. The user
# would accidentally pull and run the attacker's image and code rather than the
# intended content. We recommend only adding registries which are completely
# trusted (i.e., registries which don't allow unknown or anonymous users to
# create accounts with arbitrary names). This will prevent an image from being
# spoofed, squatted or otherwise made insecure.  If it is necessary to use one
# of these registries, it should be added at the end of the list.
#
# # An array of host[:port] registries to try when pulling an unqualified image, in order.
unqualified-search-registries = ["registry.fedoraproject.org", "registry.access.redhat.com", "quay.io", "registry.redhat.io", "docker.io"]

[[registry]]
location = "docker.io"

[[registry]]
location = "registry.fedoraproject.org"

[[registry]]
location = "registry.access.redhat.com"

# # The "prefix" field is used to choose the relevant [[registry]] TOML table;
# # (only) the TOML table with the longest match for the input image name
# # (taking into account namespace/repo/tag/digest separators) is used.
# # 
# # The prefix can also be of the form: *.example.com for wildcard subdomain
# # matching.
# #
# # If the prefix field is missing, it defaults to be the same as the "location" field.
# prefix = "example.com/foo"
#
# # If true, unencrypted HTTP as well as TLS connections with untrusted
# # certificates are allowed.
insecure = false
#
# # If true, pulling images with matching names is forbidden.
# blocked = false
#
# # The physical location of the "prefix"-rooted namespace.
# #
# # By default, this is equal to "prefix" (in which case "prefix" can be omitted
# # and the [[registry]] TOML table can only specify "location").
# #
# # Example: Given
# #   prefix = "example.com/foo"
# #   location = "internal-registry-for-example.net/bar"
# # requests for the image example.com/foo/myimage:latest will actually work with the
# # internal-registry-for-example.net/bar/myimage:latest image.
#
# # The location can be empty iff prefix is in a
# # wildcarded format: "*.example.com". In this case, the input reference will
# # be used as-is without any rewrite.
# location = internal-registry-for-example.com/bar"
#
# # (Possibly-partial) mirrors for the "prefix"-rooted namespace.
# #
# # The mirrors are attempted in the specified order; the first one that can be
# # contacted and contains the image will be used (and if none of the mirrors contains the image,
# # the primary location specified by the "registry.location" field, or using the unmodified
# # user-specified reference, is tried last).
# #
# # Each TOML table in the "mirror" array can contain the following fields, with the same semantics
# # as if specified in the [[registry]] TOML table directly:
# # - location
# # - insecure
# [[registry.mirror]]
# location = "example-mirror-0.local/mirror-for-foo"
# [[registry.mirror]]
# location = "example-mirror-1.local/mirrors/foo"
# insecure = true
# # Given the above, a pull of example.com/foo/image:latest will try:
# # 1. example-mirror-0.local/mirror-for-foo/image:latest
# # 2. example-mirror-1.local/mirrors/foo/image:latest
# # 3. internal-registry-for-example.net/bar/image:latest
# # in order, and use the first one that exists.

short-name-mode="enforcing"
```

And my podman info show this:

```
host:
  arch: arm64
  buildahVersion: 1.26.1
  cgroupControllers:
  - cpu
  - io
  - memory
  - pids
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.1.0-2.fc36.aarch64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.1.0, commit: '
  cpuUtilization:
    idlePercent: 99.24
    systemPercent: 0.57
    userPercent: 0.18
  cpus: 1
  distribution:
    distribution: fedora
    variant: coreos
    version: "36"
  eventLogger: journald
  hostname: localhost.localdomain
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 1000000
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 502
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 1000000
  kernel: 5.18.5-200.fc36.aarch64
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: journald
  memFree: 1710329856
  memTotal: 2051960832
  networkBackend: netavark
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: crun-1.4.5-1.fc36.aarch64
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 1.4.5
      commit: c381048530aa750495cf502ddb7181f2ded5b400
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +YAJL
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/user/502/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.2.0-0.2.beta.0.fc36.aarch64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.2.0-beta.0
      commit: 477db14a24ff1a3de3a705e51ca2c4c1fe3dda64
      libslirp: 4.6.1
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.3
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 31m 32.31s
plugins:
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  docker.io:
    Blocked: false
    Insecure: false
    Location: docker.io
    MirrorByDigestOnly: false
    Mirrors: null
    Prefix: docker.io
    PullFromMirror: ""
  registry.access.redhat.com:
    Blocked: false
    Insecure: false
    Location: registry.access.redhat.com
    MirrorByDigestOnly: false
    Mirrors: null
    Prefix: registry.access.redhat.com
    PullFromMirror: ""
  registry.fedoraproject.org:
    Blocked: false
    Insecure: false
    Location: registry.fedoraproject.org
    MirrorByDigestOnly: false
    Mirrors: null
    Prefix: registry.fedoraproject.org
    PullFromMirror: ""
  search:
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /var/home/core/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 3
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 3
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /var/home/core/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 106825756672
  graphRootUsed: 3025149952
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 3
  runRoot: /run/user/502/containers
  volumePath: /var/home/core/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 4.1.0
  Built: 1653926672
  BuiltTime: Mon May 30 11:04:32 2022
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.18.2
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/arm64
  Version: 4.1.0
```

I don't know how I need to make that in search registries can use others than docker.io, just like a detail, I'm using a MacOS Monterrey with a homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

I can solve this problem, the VM that create for execute podman don't use de /etc/containers/registries.conf to search, use the file /etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf
But the config to aprove an insecure container and other parameters is in the default configuration

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is for you to backup, then recreate your podman machine (or not, at your own risk):

```
podman machine stop
podman machine rm
podman machine init
```

ssh into it

```
podman machine ssh
```

then, from the podman machine VM shell

```
[core@localhost ~]$ sudo vi /etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf
```

and replace the contents by

```
unqualified-search-registries = ["registry.fedoraproject.org", "registry.access.redhat.com", "quay.io", "registry.redhat.io", "docker.io"]
```

Comment: this is where it comes from: https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/pkg/machine/ignition.go#L442

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/16364